qt_generate_repc for CMake (3.23+)
I use C++, CMake 3.23+ and have to support Qt 5.15.2/6.x for building static library. I call qt_generate_repc, but I'd like to use target_sources, FILE_SET and BASE_DIR. When I feed add_library with source list, then it's OK.
But I'd like to combine modern CMake with qt_generate_repc. CMake produces error messages, because it can't find public generated headers (repc utility is called within qt_generate_repc via add_custom_command).
